# Automatically get keyboard for an EditText in a Dialog (Android)

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

Close cousins of this question seem to be all over StackExchange, but maybe that's why I can't find an answer...

I have an application.  Within the application, I've got a couple different Surface Views, and each of them has a couple different actions that fire up a Dialog.

My dialogs consists of an EditText (for typing in some data) and Set and Cancel buttons for acting on that data.  To type in the data, the user first touches the EditText to bring up the keyboard, then types the data, touches Done, then touches Set, and the application continues on its merry way.

I would like to find a way to shorten this, if at all possible.  Specifically, I would like to skip over the view of the dialog and go right to the view of the keyboard.  (Essentially, I want to programmatically "touch" the EditText, if that makes any sense.)

Like I said at the beginning of this, I'm not having a lot of luck, so any suggestions will be happily looked in to.  And, unfortunately, simply requesting focus in the EditText has been tried and hasn't done the trick...

R.

Comment: Updating: It was a fair bit of typing, but my solution to this (which isn't really a solution) was to build a keyboard, button by button in the Dialog.  Thank God I only wanted about 12 buttons...  That really would've sucked if I needed full QWERTY.

Comment: TL;DR: I still do not have a solution to this, so if anybody's got an idea, please throw it my way...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Sadly, my luck was not good, my Dialog continues to mock me (smugly).

Answer (score 0):

The easy and best way , is to give focus to your EditText when your open the dialogues :

```
EditText yourET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_editText);
yourET.requestFocus();
```

Comment: I think you missed the last sentence in my original post... That didn't work for me at all.  Is there something else I need to do in that sequence, perhaps wait for something to complete??